# HTML5 web app vs Native mobile apps

Tags: iphone, android, html

Hi I have been recently exploring some of the Javascript mobile frameworks that can be used for developing mobile web apps like Sencha, JQTouch, JQuery mobile etc.

I know the adv and disadvantages of both.

I just need some recent stats which show the market's adoption or opinion.

Comment: Lol, did not know that Stackoverflow usernames are not unique. Good to know

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I tried three ways to develop mobile applications.

- First method is to use frameworks that will take your html/css/js files and package them into mobile applications depending on your targets (BlackBerry, iPhone, Android, ...). I used PhoneGap (known today as Cordova). I didn't like it at all because the UI's rendering is so ugly on some devices and the user experience is broken. I had to use it with jQuery Mobile because it gave me a good UI design start. I tried some Phonegap Android generated applications on my personal device and it's really horrible. Some of them got rejected by Apple because of that ...
- Second method is to use `Appcelerator Titanium SDK`. One word to sum it up: Awesome. One language to use (javascript) to create your UI/Controller. It's so easy to learn, so powerful to develop with and it has many out-of-the-box functionnalities (like facebook API, Yahoo Query Language, ...) that will allow you to put in place solutions easily for both Android and iPhone. BlackBerry is coming soon. What I liked the most is that it converts the written Javascript into the targetted platform with the default UI. It's really great. And, above all, the UI is easily customizable (with a css like system).
  Personally, I put in place apps that can: Take a photo with the device then send it to a remote server, send messages to twitter/facebook, advanced geolocation, etc.
- Third method: Native! It would take time if you target both iPhone and Android but, the big advantage is that you can create anything you want without being tied to a Framework for areas such as games, augmented reality , etc.

In my opinion, if you want to create simple applications with some nice features (weather, twitter feeds, sending on a facebook wall, ...), use Appcelerator Titanium SDK.
It converts your code into NATIVE.

If you have time to spend learning native languages, do it. It's the best way ;)

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 6):

I've summed up my thoughts on the whole "native vs. web" discussion in a blog post here: http://www.springenwerk.com/2011/09/thoughts-on-mobile-ui-design.html

In a nutshell: You can't get around getting to know the platform you are targeting if you want to provide a great user experience. Plus, you shouldn't try to mimic native UI/UX in a web application, it will only disappoint your users.

Comment: Hey mate, I read your complete blog and you've given a very good description that users will always compare your web app with native and UI can't be copied.

Just need your thought on this. I'm building an app for a small magento store, I don't have experience with native. For a slick UI, should I use (jQuery mobile + phonegap) or appcelrator Titanium?

Comment: @vipul_vj Thanks, mate! If jQuery and Titanium are really your only two choices, I'd say that Titanium will produce the better user experience because it uses native components at runtime. However, learning Titanium might be just as much work as learning iOS development. See https://www.codeschool.com/paths/ios

Answer (score 4):

here are some pros and cons of native apps vs. web apps:

**Native apps:**

- Native apps have more security
- Native apps have higher user engagement, it has higher click-through rate (CTR) among the ad-serving publishers
- When it comes to aesthetics and overall user experience, it is incredibly difficult for web apps to trump native apps
- you don't have to buy a server and maintain it, therefore, for small businesses it is the ideal solution, not web apps which require a server.

**Web apps:**

- it's cross platform  - that means your one app will work on both iphone and android
- cheaper and faster to develop and maintain
- you will find programmers easier than native apps
- updates are easier

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post for some more opinion - http://www.thorntech.com/2013/01/html5-vs-native-apps-which-will-win-the-mobile-app-development-battle/

In particular, the last paragraph is worth noting. If you go down the path of building an HTML5 app, it is worth having some type of background "syncing" of content so you are not always pulling it from the web in real time. The app will be much more responsive if you load HTML pages from disk.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the success rate of a native apps are much better than html or javascript based ones.  I do not have sufficient numbers to back it up, but these are some issues that may crop up when trying to build html5 apps for different platforms. e.g.

1. Browser OS or webkit differences can cause unexpected bugs,  css issues that could take quite a while to debug.
2. Your app is running on top of a webkit browser engine which takes up additional resources.
3. Older or non-smart phone devices may not have a modern webkit engine.

Nevertheless if you have good web skills over native, then getting an app to the market the quicket and cheapest route would be html5.   Some apps lend very well for html5 such as data listing, and text content driven apps.  I have written a writeup on [HTML5 vs Native](http://www.cabotsolutions.com/2013/03/html-5-vs-native-vs-hybrid-is-the-jury-finally-in/) on my blog.  Hope its useful.