# Android App: Web vs Native

Tags: android, facebook

I want to develop an Android application with some Facebook features. What is the best way to develop this app, if I want to filter and process some data returned from timeline?

Answer (score 4):

If you are a beginner and have Javascript skills, go with Titanium. It's a very good framework that turns your javascript code into full native.
All your code is Javascript and there is a set of very useful APIs [like the Facebook one](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook-module).

Otherwise, if you are comfortable with Java then, the best alternative is to go native. There is an [official Facebook SDK for Android](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/385/).

If you have more questions about "Web vs Native", you may find some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097952/how-do-start-with-complex-level-cross-platform-mobile-application-development/9098699#9098699) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548517/html5-web-app-vs-native-mobile-apps/5548935#5548935).

Comment: I don't want to use Titanium, PhoneGap or other frameworks. I was thinking to load in a WebView the Facebook PHP SDK (hosted on a web server) or use Facebook SDK for Android. Oficial Facebook APP is a native app with a webview that sends' requests on http://m.facebook.com?